# UIPercentDrivenInteractiveTransition captures all sublayer animations

Tags: ios, animation, custom-transition

I have created an interactive transition using **UIPercentDrivenInteractiveTransition**

Problem I'm having is that percent driven transition is also capturing those animations which are in **toVC**

Is there a way to make them independent?